# How to stop a reduce function from processing the list once the desired accumulation has been reached?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

In the procedural world, if I have to find the first item of a list that meets a test, I would just use `break` or `return`.

In Clojure, when I am processing a list using `reduce` to find that first value, won't it be inefficient if I continue and process the entire list?

For example: validating a list of dictionaries for errors; each dictionary has a key called `count`.  Now the total sum of these count fields in the list should not exceed a certain value.  How do I find the first item in the list where the sum exceeds the limit ?

Ideally, I would use `reduce` and maintain a running total; as soon as the total exceeds the limit, I would like to stop there (which I can't figure out how to do).

Also, the return value of the reduce will be the sum till now everytime but I would need to return the index at the end of all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`reduced`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduced) function to terminate a reduction:

```
(reduce (fn [sum x] 
          (if (> sum 10) 
            (reduced 10) 
            (+ sum x))) 
        0 
        [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10])
```

Comment: Oh wow! something like this exists. but I need to return the position at which this happens otherwise return -1.

but if return index in reduce, how do I accumulate sum.

Shall i put both values in a map or list ? and return it with both values end of every reduce call ?

Comment: Yes, you can update the index in the accumulator. Something like (fn [acc x] (if (> (:sum acc) 10) (reduced acc) (assoc acc :idx (inc (:idx acc)) :sum (+ (:sum acc) x))).

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to use [`reductions`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reductions) rather than [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce) to find the break point. This is a lot slower than [@Jonas's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23822576/1562315), but allows us to exercise some of the sequence library.

Given, for example

```
(def data [{:count 19}
           {:count 93}
           {:count 89}
           {:count 91}
           {:count 55}
           {:count 22}
           {:count 22}
           {:count 22}
           {:count 40}
           {:count 89}])
```

then

```
(reductions + (map :count data))
; (19 112 201 292 347 369 391 413 453 542)
```

... returns the sequence of accumulated `:count` values.

Let's suppose the limit is `300`. Then

```
(let [acceptable (take-while
                   (partial >= 300)
                   (reductions + (map :count data)))]
  acceptable)
; (19 112 201 292)
```

... returns the initial sub-sequence that meets the limit criterion. This tells us both things we want to know:

- Its `last` element is the accumulated `:count`.
- Its length - returned, confusingly, by function [`count`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/count) - is the position, counting from 0, of the first refused element.

You can use the length, for example, to split the original sequence into accepted and refused parts:

```
(let [acceptable (take-while ...)]
  (split-at (count acceptable) data))
; [({:count 19} {:count 93} {:count 89} {:count 91})
;  ({:count 55} {:count 22} {:count 22} {:count 22} {:count 40} {:count 89})]
```

If we know that the original sequence is a vector, we can use `subvec` to pull out its parts much quicker.

```
(let [acceptable (take-while ...)
      point (count acceptable)]
  [(subvec data 0 point) (subvec data point)])
; [[{:count 19} {:count 93} {:count 89} {:count 91}]
;  [{:count 55} {:count 22} {:count 22} {:count 22} {:count 40} {:count 89}]]
```